# Tail Recursive Double Factorial on C - Integer division by zero

Tags: c

I am trying to write a code that caculates the double factorial of an intiger with a tail recursion by the following formula : [DoubleFactorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMEKk.gif).

Here is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

// Test cases: 5!! = 15; 10!! = 3840;

long long Factorial(int n) {
    if (n < 0) // assignment assumption
        return 0;
    if (n == 0) // stopping condition
        return 1;
    return n * Factorial(n - 1); // non-tail recursive step
}

 int tail_recursion_double_factorial(int n, int accumulator) {
    if (n < 0) // assignment assumption
        return 0;
    if (n == 0) // stopping condition
        return accumulator;
    if (n == 1) // stopping condition -- return the most updated counter
        return accumulator;
    return Factorial(n) / tail_recursion_double_factorial(n - 1, n*accumulator); // TAIL RECURSIVE step -- using formula for double factorial
}

int main() {
    int n;
    long long res; //res doesn't have to be of type int.
    printf("Please enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    res = tail_recursion_double_factorial(n,1); // assigning the recursive call to a variable
    printf("%d!! = %ld", n, res); // NOTE: IF YOU CHANGE THE TYPE OF RES - CHANGE THE SPECIAL CHARACTHER SPECIFIER (%) ACCORDINGLY
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason im getting the following error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3J1Eo.jpg)

I tried everything and im not sure what causes this error -- i cant see where the division by zero problem might happen.

Comment: Multiply the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. giving 1, 2, 6, 24 etc. and print the results. Tell us when the result behaves strange, and when it becomes zero. Then think hard about why that happens.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to just keep the n==0 condition to end your functions.
Because in both function you just descrease n by 1, it will have to pass by 0, this is where it will stop.

Also you can check that the input n is a valid > 1 number

Answer (score 0):

try to keep the recursion of n-1 without multiplying by n

```
    int tail_recursion_double_factorial(int n, int accumulator) {
        if (n < 0) // assignment assumption
            return 0;
        if (n == 0) // stopping condition
            return accumulator;
        if (n == 1) // stopping condition -- return the most updated counter
            return accumulator;
        return Factorial(n) / tail_recursion_double_factorial(n - 1, accumulator); // TAIL RECURSIVE step -- using formula for double factorial
}
```